# Invalid property name: `errorType` on class `java.lang.String`. Validate that the correct setters is present

Tags: json, logging, mule, mulesoft, mule4

When I try to use a [json-logger](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/json-logging-mule-4/) in Mule 4. I'm getting this error. I'm trying to log a error object here but it is not getting successfull. Please find the error object below.

[image: json-logger properties]

[image: error-object]

Comment: Which is the Mule 4 exact version?

Comment: Did you see the error in the log? You should share the complete error from the log.

Comment: Guys. Thank you for the comments. I sorted out the issue. The issue was we cannot give JSON in the MESSAGE section of json-logger. When i changed it to a string. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted out the issue. **The issue was we cannot give JSON in the MESSAGE section of json-logger. When i changed it to a string**. It worked

**The MESSAGE section is meant to describe what you are going to Log.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the function stringifyNonJSON() with a Mule error and treat it like a String. Without more details of the flow and the payload it is not possible to have more insights.

You could try to create a string from the payload manually first and use that as the parameter, as the function is not able to handle this case apparently.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I sorted out the issue. The issue was we cannot give JSON in the MESSAGE section of json-logger. When i changed it to a string. It worked.